# Valores repetidos en DataFrame en R

Tags: r, dataframe, rstudio

Tengo el siguiente Data Frame con precipitaciones por localidad de Argentina. El problema es que por ejemplo para Córdoba Capital y Castellanos tengo tres valores para un mismo mes y año entonces necesito poder resumir esa información como promedio y que en el data frame quede solo una fila con Córdoba Capital con el valor promedio.

```
`codigo anio mes precip.mensual     departamento provincia
  87244 2000  11          137.5         Rio seco        CO
  87244 2000  12          150.5         Rio seco        CO
  87257 2000   1          150.5    San cristobal        SF
  87257 2000   2          125.9    San cristobal        SF
  87344 2000   1           96.8          Capital        CO
  87344 2000   2          135.2          Capital        CO
  87344 2000   3          184.6          Capital        CO
  87344 2000   4          125.4          Capital        CO
  87344 2000   5           47.0          Capital        CO
  87344 2000   6            0.0          Capital        CO
  87344 2000   7           12.0          Capital        CO
  87344 2000   8            0.5          Capital        CO
  87344 2000   9           14.0          Capital        CO
  87344 2000  10          124.2          Capital        CO
  87344 2000  11          192.0          Capital        CO
  87344 2000  12          175.0          Capital        CO
  87345 2000   1          150.8          capital        CO
  87345 2000   2          136.6          capital        CO
  87345 2000   3          105.1          capital        CO
```

`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo puedes hacer mediante `dplyr` agrupando y sumarizando:

```
df %>%
   group_by(anio, mes, departamento, provincia) %>%
   summarize(precip.mensual = mean(precip.mensual))
```